# Calling Stored Procedures from Cloud Dataflow code

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is it possible to directly call the 'Stored Procedures' from Cloud Dataflow code. I have dumped some data into Bigquery table and on those data I would like to apply a stored procedure (used when these data ware in SQL system). Can I use the same stored procedure in Dataflow codes as well or any workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, BigQuery does not have support for stored procedures. In your Dataflow pipeline, you can issue normal SQL to BigQuery from within the pipeline itself or outside it.